# Is there a command to check how many pages are in a PDF?

Tags: windows, vbscript, notepad

I am trying to declare a new variable "x" on a vbscript using notepad. I was hoping there is a command for the script to check a PDF and return "y" amount of pages to variable "x"

Comment: There's no any built-in functionality in VBScript to work with PDF. But quick googling gives this http://www.quickpdflibrary.com/help/getting-started-activex.php

Comment: In the past whenever I've needed to work with PDFs in VBScript *(usually in connection with Classic ASP)* I've used [Persits PDF component](http://www.asppdf.com/), which for PDF work I would highly recommend.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.I have tested the code and giving the page count.Just copy the code in a notepad,provide your pdf file path and make it vbs file and run.

```
sPath="C:/Users/kajalk/Downloads/Testing_Newsletter_ April 2018.pdf"
set objpdf=CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
with objpdf
  .Open
  .Charset = "x-ansi"
  .LoadFromFile sPath
   strReadfile = .ReadText(-1)
end With
With (New RegExp)
        .Pattern = "Type\s*/Page[^s]"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        getPdfPgCnt = .Execute(strReadfile).Count
End With 

Msgbox getPdfPgCnt
```

Please let me know you if this works.

Comment: Sorry I don’t know any such command.Could you please accept my code if it works.